# How to calculate co-occurence in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data in the following format which is in the float datatype. I wanted to calculate the co-occurrence for skill_id and use the co-occurrence in the format below. I am new to python and confused about how to do it with numbers.

My data is in the following format

```
skill_id
0   1589682.0,972614.0,959423.0,958546.0,7547697.0...
1   954981.0,954651.0,972914.0,955590.0,958410.0,1...
2   955590.0,972787.0,957701.0,1906300.0,972842.0,...
3   958250.0,955622.0,1587760.0,958678.0,972565.0
4   1588624.0,972568.0,974186.0,972961.0,972823.0,...
```

I am trying to calculate

```
skill1  skill2  count
0   9728040 9728230 1
1   9728040 9747140 1
2   9556490 9741860 1
```

I have used the following code for my data but I am able to get a count of 1, not more than 1, but when I am inserting new data manually, I am able to get a count greater than 1

```
def count(w1, w2):
    c = 0
    for row in data['skill_id']:
        n = len(row)
        if n<=1: return c
        
        for i in range(n-1) :
            if row[i]==w1 and row[i+1]==w2: c+=1
            elif row[i]==w2 and row[i+1]==w1: c+=1
            i+=1
    return c

with open(r'output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["skill1", "skill2", "count"])
    for i, word1 in enumerate(unique_words):
        print("writing:", round(i*100/n_unique, 1), "%         ", end="\r")
        
        # it writes only if the count is a positive value, you can just remove the condition if you want
        # but the output file size would be rather large
        for word2 in unique_words:
            c = count(word1, word2)
            if c>0: writer.writerow([word1, word2, c])
print("------- finished -------")
```

Comment: I don't see you using pandas or a data frame here, are you asking how to debug your code or to convert it to pandas/data frames patterns?

Comment: I wanted to convert it into pandas or data frame patterns. As mentioned above the pattern should have columns like skill1,skill2, and count.